# Finding user roles in one query Microsoft Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

So I know there are "similar" questions but not quite like I'd want to implement this.

My issue is that I want to check whether a user is in any of the roles specified in a method like so:

```
public bool HasUserGotAnyRoles(string userId, List<string> roleNames) {}
```

I am aware of the fact that you could be using the `ApplicationUserManager` to take care of this but for me this is not possible because I have a separate project for my bussiness logic.

Thus I will have to create a query myself to check if a user has got any of the list of roles provided, and if so, return that he has.

Thinking this would have been easy, it turns out it isn't.

I'm using Linq and when I do `db.Users.Include(x => x.Roles)`, this return me the `AspNetUserRoles` which only contain the `userId` and `roleId`.

Does anyone know how I can filter the roles linked to my user by rolenames and return a boolean if so? I've been trying to use LinqPad to get a view of what could work but to no success so far.

Bear in mind that I would want this to be done in **one** query. Not multiple.

**Edit**

I came up with this:

```
 public bool HasUserGotAnyRoles(string userId, List<string> roleNames)
 {
        var userRoles = Db.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).Single(x => x.Id == userId).Roles;
        var result = userRoles.Any(x => Db.Roles.Where(y => roleNames.Contains(y.Name)).Select(y => y.Id).Contains(x.RoleId));
        return result;
 }
```

But this is ugly for one and executes 3 queries to get my result. I'd love to have this in one query if possible.